# How to avoid Jest warnings: A "describe" callback must not return a value?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, arrow-functions

After upgrading Jest from version 23 to version 24, when running my tests, I get a warning message like this for almost every test:

> A "describe" callback must not return a value.
>   Returning a value from "describe" will fail the test in a future version of Jest.

The accompaying stack trace points to this module:

```
addSpecsToSuite (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:443:15)
```

The reason for this is that I like to use the short-hand version of arrow-functions for my tests, omitting curly braces when the function body contains only one statement, for example:

```
describe('true', () =>
    it('should be truthy', () =>
        expect(true).toBeTruthy()));
```

The `it` statement apparently returns something other than `undefined`, hence the warning.

I've found two ways of fixing this:

**① Don't Use Shorthand Arrow Functions**

```
describe('true', () => {
    it('should be truthy', () =>
        expect(true).toBeTruthy());
});
```

**② Use `void` to Force Returning Undefined**

```
describe('true', () =>
    void it('should be truthy', () =>
        expect(true).toBeTruthy()));
```

I find neither of these options acceptable, I don't want to refactor thousands of tests just to make Jest (or Jasmine) happy.

So my question is:

**Is there a way of configuring Jest so that these warnings are not issued when using shorthand arrow functions?**

Comment: Any specific reason other than personal preference that you need to use shorthand syntax? This seems to be 100% resolvable by adding braces.

Comment: Personal preference, I'm just used to it, and I like the concise syntax

Comment: I've been getting the same warning with a slightly different stack trace regardless of whether my `describe()`s use shorthand arrow functions or not. Turns out it's a bug in PhpStorm to be resolved in v2018.3.6. Workaround can be found here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003251559-Error-running-tests-from-editor-with-jest-24-?flash_digest=8da09960025d1b74d6145c5f718bba3268ccddba

Comment: This also happens when you nest a describe within a describe. These changes are bugs. If I have time I'll report this on the repo.

Comment: @Ionix Well, the fact that they give out a detailed deprecation warning makes it seem like it's not a bug, but a feature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess if you really want to keep your existing test syntax and just want to avoid the warning you can do this:

```js
const realDescribe = describe;
describe = ((name, fn) => { realDescribe(name, () => { fn(); }); });
```

Just add that code to a module included in your [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) and it will run "immediately after the test framework has been installed in the environment" and "before each test".

The above code will set the global `describe` to a function that calls the real `describe` but wraps the `function` parameter in an anonymous function that doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 4):

This problem also shows up if you're using global functions that Jest v24 doesn't recognize. I'm converting some Mocha tests to Jest, and Mocha's `before()` was throwing the same error:

> A "describe" callback must not return a value. Returning a value from "describe" will fail the test in a future version of Jest.

The stack trace pointed to `describe()` being the culprit, but the fix was converting the nested `before()` calls to a Jest-compatible `beforeAll()`. There might be a related issue here with trying to use `it()` instead of `test()`, but that might be grasping, there's definitely an `it()` in Jest's test environment.

Answer (score 0):

May be related to an unhandled exception thrown inside describe callback. 
For example, occurred to me when I wanted to access mock of non existing member (outside of test block):

```
logger.info1111.mockImplementation((m, d) => console.info(m, d));
```